# Why doesn't Google use Golang or python as the language for android?

Tags: android, go

While go language has so many good advantages,why Google didn't migrant Android from java step by step to Go,or give the choice to developers?

Comment: Good question, but it should be in the meta section!

Comment: Ask to Google, not here.

Comment: It's a developer's Site..for discussion go to meta.stackoverflow.com Instead.

Comment: hmmm never heard of it before. Is it really famous and good enough? :D

Answer (score 8):

Python isn't that fast for general tasks and isn't so much used for gui based applications. And clear and closed API definition isn't a strength of the language.

Go language didn't even exist when the company Google later bought made the Android OS. It doesn't have a sandboxing model which seems to be an important requirement today.

The sandboxed and fast java language made a very reasonable choice at that time. The big number of java coders would still today make it a better choice than the relatively unknown Go language as platform first choice. Google was very interested from the start to have many coders making app (they even distributed many free devices) so using an unknown language would have made no sense.

Note that there always are requests coming from the Go community asking for the Go language on Android but providing all requested API wouldn't be a light task and Google never publicly promised to try to do it.

Comment: >>It doesn't have a sandboxing model which seems to be an important requirement today.

Go is memory safe like Java and as far as sandboxing you could use any combination of Go's sandboxing (how do you think http://play.golang.org/ or appengine works...), chjail or better yet Linux kernel containers/cgroups/namespace isolation.

Answer (score 5):

Giving a choice to developers is always nice, but the reason behind using java as the standard      instead of a new language like Go, is that java is more widely used (by far) meaning their app market would expand at a much faster rate; yielding a faster return on investment.